# Активируется vs активизируется

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова

1. How to chose between these two words?
2. Which one should I use here:

   > кнопка 'Отправить' активи(зи?)руется только когда заполнены все поля

Comment: Speaking about activating and deactivating UI controls the "standard" (from the books) translation is "активировать" и "деактивировать".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Кнопка активируется, когда заполнены все поля.

**Активировать** means *to turn on,**to make active*** what didn't work,to start a process. activate.

**Активизировать** means **to make a process more active**, to increase productivity or speed.